# Erlang: starting slave node

Tags: erlang, cluster-computing

I'm trying to start Erlang slave node on cluster and I receive `bash: erl: command not found` message. Though I have alias for erl. Here is what I actually do:

```
[user@n001 ~]$ erl -rsh ssh -sname n001    
Eshell V5.7.5  (abort with ^G)
    (n001@n001)1> slave:start_link("user@n002", n002, "-rsh ssh").
    bash: erl: command not found
                                {error,timeout}
    (n001@n001)2>
```

Maybe, there is something wrong?
Thanks.

UPDATE:
I've added Erlang bin dir to my `$PATH` variable; I've set `$ERLANG_ROOT_DIR` variable; created `symlink` in `~/` to `erl` - but nothing have changed...
I have installed Erlang in `~/bin/erlang` dir...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble was in bash:
Actually erlang connects to node via ssh, invoking default sh in non-interactive mode.
But when bash is started in non-interactive mode, it doesn't read .bashrc where my path variables and aliases are stored.
So I switched to zsh and all is ok now! ;)

Comment: `.bashrc` usually contains the following line near the top:

    # If not running interactively, don't do anything
    [ -z "$PS1" ] && return

So if you define your `PATH` variable before that, you can use your custom `erl`. Bash *does* read .bashrc in non-interactive mode.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the alias won't be honored

erl needs to actually be in your path

Also, I believe that your .bashrc doesn't execute either.  So you may have to symlink "erl" to /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin

Comment: Thanks for trying to help..but..
I've added erlang bin dir to my $PATH variable; I've set $ERLANG_ROOT_DIR variable; created symlink in ~/ to erl - but nothing have changed...
Btw, I have installed erlang in ~/bin/erlang dir...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using [a wrong format](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/slave.html#start_link-3) for the Host field of start_link/3;

It should be an atom representing the host where the node Name (second parameter, also an atom) should be started, resulting in node Name@Host.

So in your case that would be

```
slave:start_link('n002', 'n002', "-rsh ssh").
```

Comment: Thanks, but slave:start_link('n002', 'n002', "-rsh ssh"). executes with the same result - 
> slave:start_link('n002', 'n002', "-rsh ssh").
bash: erl: command not found
                            {error,timeout}

Answer (score 0):

my guess is erlang cookie.

can you ping n002 ?
if yes, then do the two nodes have the same cookie ?

for example you can try:
erl -sname abc -rsh ssh -setcookie secretcookie

erl> slave:start(n002, name, "-setcookie secretcookie"). %% so these two nodes share a cookie

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
>ssh user@n002 erl
```

to check if erl is ok on n002.